# initialising array of vectors in constructor

Tags: arrays, oop, c++11, vector

I have a class named Graph. There this vertices member of the class. I have initialized vertices in the constructor. Also, There is a member array of vectors. I want the number of vectors to be equal to vertices. for example if vertices = 5 then my array of vectors should look like this.
vector v[5];
How can I do this in the constructor as I will only know the value of vertices in the constructor?

```
class Graph
{

private:
    int vertices;
    std::vector<int> adj[];
public:
    Graph(int v); //constructor
    // add an edge
    void addEdge(int u, int v);
    //print bfs traversal of graph
    void bfs(int s); // s is a source from where bfs traversal should 
                     //start

};

Graph :: Graph(int v)
{
   vertices = v;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you only know the value of your vertices at run-time, you cannot use a C-style array or a `std::array`, as those require the size to be known at compile-time.

You can use another vector instead:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> adj;
```

Comment: can I use it with new memory allocation? Like this: adj = new vector<int> (vertices);

Comment: @GauravSahu Why would you? The outer `std::vector` handles allocation himself. In general, prefer ***not*** to do manual allocation, - this is higly error-prone, and you can go with standard containers 95-99% of the time.

Comment: @lisyarus  I am new to STL. How would I initialize the vector of vectors in the constructor?